# delete then rename: same filenames different extensions

Tags: filenames, rename, rm, delete

I have a directory containing thousands of files, each file has a duplicate.
An example:

```
file1.txt
file1.jpg.txt

file2.txt
file2.jpg.txt
```

I want to delete all *.txt files, and leave the *.jpg.txt
then afterwards I want to rename all *.jpg.txt to *.txt only

I am running on OpenSuse 12

Comment: You don't necessarily need to delete the set of of files before applying the rename. This will allow you to match on `*.jpg.txt`. There are many "rename" questions and answers here on [unix.se] so use those as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @roaima mentioned, you do not need to first remove the files, when moving the files you would automatically overwrite the old files.

One approach to this is to use a for loop in bash:

```
for f in *.jpg.txt; do mv $f ${f/%.jpg.txt/.txt}; done
```

Let me explain:

- `for f in *.jpg.txt; do <command>; done`: Execute command on each file of `*.jpg.txt`. While executing the filename is stored in variable `f`.
- `${f/%.jpg.txt/.txt}`: The value of `$f`, but the last occurrence of `.jpg.txt` is replaced with `.txt`. See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html for more examples of this.
- `mv $f ${f/%.jpg.txt/.txt}`: Do the renaming of the old file to the new file name without the `.jpg`.

Before running this code, you can assure yourself, that it will to the right thing by running

```
for f in *.jpg.txt; do echo $f ${f/%.jpg.txt/.txt}; done
```

This will print out the pairs of files that will be moved.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

## to remove ".txt" files

# this will keep the files which removing in txt
# you can see delete file on the script path
ls -lrth | grep ".txt" | grep -v "jpg" | awk -F' ' {'print $9'} > delete
terminal=`tty`
exec < ${delete=delete}
        while read line
        do
                rm -rf $line
        done
exec < $terminal


## Renaming the files
# this will keep the files which we are renaming
# you can see rename file on the script path
ls -lrth | grep -i "jpg" | awk -F' ' {'print $9'} > rename 
terminal=`tty`
exec < ${rename=rename}
        while read line
        do
                nn=`echo $line | sed 's/.jpg//gi'`
                mv $line $nn
        done
exec < $terminal
```